# In RAW can a player choose to go later in initiative order?

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative

I know a player can hold an action as per the hold action rules, but can they decide to take entire turn further down the initiative order?

If they do is this there initiative position for all subsequent turns or do they go back in order the next round?